# Trying to avoid sending emails when email address ends with ".old"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, actionmailer

I have a requirement to override ActionMailer's `mail` method. This method is protected so in the subclass, I also define the `mail` method as protected:

```
protected

def mail(headers={}, &block)
  #add a check to avoid sending emails that end with ".old"
  unless headers[:to] =~ /\.old$/
    super(headers, &block)
  end
end
```

this way, when an outgoing email address ends with `.old`, the method should return nil and not send an email.

However, in my  unit test, it seems that an email is still going to `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries`

here is my unit test:

```
describe 'BaseNotifier' do

  class TestNotifier < BaseNotifier
    def mailer(to, from, subject)
      mail(:to => to,
          :from => from,
          :subject => subject)
    end
  end

  before(:each) do
    ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :test
    ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
  end

  it "should not send emails to a user with an email that ends in '.old'" do
    TestNotifier.mailer("some_email@gmail.com.old", "from@gmail.com", "test email").deliver
    puts "what do we have here " + ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.first.to_s
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.length.should == 0
  end
end
```

I create a test class and subclass the class where mail is overridden (this is how it will be used in the system). I then make an email and call the `.deliver` method.

UPDATE: i think the deliver method is not the issue. When I do this: `puts TestNotifier.mailer("some_email@gmail.com.old", "from@gmail.com", "test email")` I get the same email message as below. I also tried to override the mail method in this way:

```
def mail(headers={}, &block)
  #add a check to avoid sending emails that end with ".old"
  unless headers[:to] =~ /\.old$/
    super(headers, &block)
  else
    super({:to=>nil, :from=>nil, :boundary =>nil, :date => nil, :message =>nil, :subject =>nil, :mime_version => nil,
           :content_type => nil, :charset =>nil, :content_transfer_encoding => nil}, &block)
  end

end
```

which gives me a failure with `undefined method 'ascii_only?' for nil:NilClass` on this line: `TestNotifier.mailer("some_email@gmail.com.old", "from@gmail.com", "test email").deliver`

UPDATE: I've also tried doing this with the overridden `mail` method:

#create a class that overrides the deliver method to do nothing.
   class NonSendingEmail; def deliver; end; end

def mail(headers={}, &block)
     #add a check to avoid sending emails that end with ".old"
     unless headers[:to] =~ /.old$/
       super(headers, &block)
     else
       NonSendingEmail.new
     end
   end

but i'm still having the same result.

<del>It seems like the `deliver` method is generating an empty email?</del> What I'd like to do is have nothing generated at all. Here is the email from the deliveries array:

```
Date: Thu, 19 Jan 2012 00:00:00 +0000
Message-ID: <4f18344f94d0_12267803589ac2731d@Ramys-MacBook-Pro.local.mail>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

Comment: I think the problem is the fact that rails instanciate **its mailer class** and not yours, so your mailer class maybe it's not even used

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL, when/where does rails instantiate its mailer class? which mailer class do you mean when you say my mailer class may not be used? `TestNotifier.mailer`? Or the overridden `mail` method?

Comment: Nope I mean ActionMailer class, I don't really know where it is instanciated, but maybe rails keep instanciating ActionMailer class and not YourActionMailer.new. Be aware that I'm **supposing** it otherwise I would have post this as an answer, but hopefully this comment can point to what you should search for

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL, that's not true; you are free to subclass.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are editing the wrong place. changing the mail method to return nil won't help as the mailer then uses an empty message. you can instead patch the mail class (working with rails 3):

```
module Mail
  class Message
    alias :old_deliver :deliver
    def deliver
      old_deliver unless to.first =~ /\.old$/
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: where would I put this? It's own file and then `include` it in the BaseNotifier? Going to have to try this in a few hours.

Comment: THANK YOU! I just put this at the top of my BaseNotifier.rb before the class definition. Worked like a charm.

Comment: i would put it in `lib/gem_ext/mail/mail/message.rb` cause this reflects that you are extending the mail gem.

Answer (score 3):

You can set perform_deliveries for the message to false, e.g.

```
after_filter :do_not_send_if_old_email

def do_not_send_if_old_email
  message.perform_deliveries = false if to.first =~ /\.old$/
  true
end
```